# Takeoff-chart Interpolating Numbers from a range

Tags: takeoff, theory

I'm studying for my AIRAT (Instructor Written) in Canada using Nizus, but I've always had trouble answering the questions about takeoff distances at 27 ºC when given [a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKKU7.png) with 20 ºC and 30 ºC, even since the start of PPL. I want to understand it properly so I can effectively teach my students who have troubles with it.

The question is a two-parter, first calculating a takeoff distance with the following values:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Airport Temp | 30 ºC |
| Airport Elevation | 3000' AMSL |
| Altimeter | 30.92 inHg |
| Wind | 10 kt tailwind |
| Flaps | 10º |
| Runway | Dry grass |

With a pressure altitude of 2089', the nearest values are the 2000' and 3000'. I used the 2000' line of the chart.

At 2000' at 20 ºC the ground roll is 1080' and the total to clear a 50' obstacle is 1895'.
At 30 ºC it's 1155' and 2030'.

The chart says it's configured as follows: 2300 lbs, flaps 10, full power prior to brake release on a paved level dry runway with no wind. The notes state:
*Headwind subtract 10% per 9kts*
*Tailwind add 10% every 2kts up to 10kts*
*Dry, Grass Runway or Gravel add 15% to ground roll.*

At 30 ºC I calculate my takeoff distance being **3305'**.

---

The second part asks by how much the takeoff distance will decrease if the temperature drops to 27 ºC.

I'm doing something wrong here as I calculate it to be 3250', with a distance change of 55', but that isn't an available answer.

How do I get the proper numbers to use at 27 ºC?

Comment: this is the chart here https://i.imgur.com/9HnYWR3.png, the first question https://i.imgur.com/IGZSMxP.png, and the second https://i.imgur.com/kkKLH1p.png

Comment: Is your question really just about how to properly interpolate or is it more than that?

Comment: If the reference question was designed to see how well you can interpolate then I’d think you’d need to interpolate for both temperature and pressure.

Comment: In order to get the exact answer I'm sure you'd need to interpolate for 2089' too I guess, but I originally figured it'd be such a small difference at that scale that there'd be no need. For 27degC I originally found the numbers for 25 by adding em both together, divide by 2, then add the number for 30degC again and divide by 2. I figured that'd get me to 27.5degC, but maybe that's not how that works at all?
And I appreciate you guys taking the time to help me work this out.

Comment: I have an ASA CX-3 Flight Computer and that's what it gives, though I've never understood how this works out pressure alt as when I do it for personal flight calcs I've always just done 29.92 - 30.92 = -1 * 1000 = -1000.

Comment: See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/91615/54557) for a more precise formula to calculate pressure altitude.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting a takeoff distance of 3,502' for a takeoff over 50 FT on a **grass strip** with a **10-kt tailwind**.

> 2,030' * 1.5 * 1.15 = 3,502'

To interpolate you will need to figure out the percentage between the two temperatures.

> (27-20) / (30-20) = 70%

We take the difference between the chart values for 20 and 30 degrees

> 3,502' - 3,267' = 235'

Multiply this value by the percentage

> 235 * .7 = 164.5'

Since we subtracted the 27 from the lower value we will add in this number ot the lower chart value

> 3,267 + 164.5 = 3,432

This is a difference of 70 feet.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure altitude with Kollsman at 30.92 would be 3000 feet - 1000 feet = 2000 feet.  Dry grass **only affects ground roll**.

Distance to clear 50' obstacle at 30 C :   2030 feet

Ground roll distance:  1155 feet

30 C with 10 knot tailwind:  2030 × 1.50 = 3045 feet

Ground roll with tailwind: 1155 × 1.5 = 1732 feet

Ground roll with tailwind and grass: 1732 × 1.15 = 1992 feet

difference: 1992 - 1732 = 260 feet more

> Total distance to clear 50' at 30 C: 3045 + 260 = 3305 feet

Distance to clear 50' obstacle at 20C:  1895 feet

Ground roll distance: 1080 feet

20C with 10 knot tailwind: 1895 × 1.5 = 2842 feet

Ground roll with tailwind: 1080 × 1.5 = 1621 feet

Ground roll with tailwind and grass: 1621 × 1.15 = 1864 feet

 difference: 1864 - 1621 = 243 feet more

> Total distance to clear 50' at 20 C: 2842 + 243 = 3085 feet

3305 - 3085 = 220 feet

  220 feet÷10C = 22 feet per degree

> 22 feet per degree × 3 C = around 66 feet less at 27  C

Answers of 3305 feet and 66 feet difference seem ok!